# Add extra fields to profile page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the plugins [theme-my-login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) and [theme my profile](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-profile/) to create a front end login/registration process.

When the user registers on the site they get redirected to their profile page. Although theme my login comes with the ability to add extra fields to the register form, how can I add extra fields to the profile form?

To display and update the profile I have the shortcode `[theme-my-profile]` which displays the user profile on the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
add_filter('user_contactmethods', array(&$this, 'add_contactmethods'), 10, 1);

/**
 * Add another contact field to the user profile page
 *
 * @param array $contactmethods
 * @return array
 */
function add_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
    // Add Twitter
    $contactmethods['twitter'] = __('Twitter Username', 'twitter-avatar-reloaded');
    return $contactmethods;
}
```

PS: I copied this code from my [Twitter Avatar Reloaded WordPress Plugin](http://sudarmuthu.com/wordpress/twitter-avatar-reloaded)

Comment: Does that save the details that the user enters? Also, is it possible to add a drop down... or any other type of input?

Comment: Yes it will save the data the user enters in a custom field for the user

Comment: Is it possible to add any other type of input such as a drop down?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Check out http://codesleepshred.com/how-to-add-options-to-user-profiles-using-personal_options/